# Searching a name for a ring-like structure (if any)

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

A kind of weak-ring structure:  (S,+,*)

(1) (S,+,0) an abelian group (closure, associative, unit, inverse, commutative)

(2) (S,*,1) a monoid (closure, associative, unit) but (S{0}, *) (that means S minus additive unit) a non-abelian group.

(3)  * does not distribute (left or right) over +

How should it named?

Thanks,Peter

Comment: Wikipedia states that "Failure of one of the two distributive laws brings about near-rings and near-fields instead of rings and division rings respectively.", but you want an even weaker structure.

Comment: Thanks Santiago, that is the point. Someone could say you have two non related structures, but i am not so sure.

Comment: The operations $+$ and $*$ don't seem to interact much with each other.  What examples do you have in mind?

Comment: Think of (S, . ,1) as any non-commutative non-numeric group with elements indexed (1...n) and (S,+,0) simply equal to Z(n+1) modular group, thus you add 0 as first row and column of the multiplicative Cayley table. You end with (S+0, . ,1) as a monoid and non-distributivity holds. Thanks for your question.